# How can I test whether a string contains another string in fish shell?

Tags: fish

How do I test for the presence of a substring in fish shell? For instance, within a `switch` expression:

```
 set myvar "a long test string"
 switch $myvar
 case magical-operator-here "test string" 
     echo 'yep!'
 case '*'
     echo 'nope!'
 end
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `*` is the wildcard character, so

```
set myvar "a long test string"
switch $myvar
case "*test string" 
    echo 'yep!'
case '*'
    echo 'nope!'
end
```

If you wish to test if it *ends* with that string. If it can also appear somewhere in the middle, add another `*` at the end.

Also, since 2.3.0, fish has had a `string` builtin with a `match` subcommand, so you could also use `string match -q -- "*test string" $myvar`. It also supports pcre-style regexes with the "-r" option.

Comment: I always appreciate your StackOverflow answers related to fish shell. 

Comment: Thanks! The `string match` command is what I'm looking for.

Comment: "If it can also appear somewhere in the middle, add another * at the end." Like this. `set myvar "a long test string"
switch $myvar
case "*test string*" 
    echo 'yep!'
case '*'
    echo 'nope!'
end`